# Why thread did not work on sniff() function on python scapy?

Tags: python, scapy

I have a code, i want to run the function `cek_paket()` and `delete_paket()` at the same time. My friend suggest me to use thread. So shortly, im using this to sniffing arp packet, and save the information (source, destination address,and the amount of packet arrived) into list in dictionary python. So `sniff()` function is the function by scapy that i use to sniff packet. After the packet arrive, it will return it to `cek_paket()` to save the information to jumlah_reply list. And i use `delete_reply()` to delete the first list(jumlah_reply[0]) every 3 second.  I have no problem in `cek_paket()` function. The problem is, why the `sniffing()` function only works? But delete_reply function did not work?

```
from scapy.all import*
import thread
import time
jumlah_reply = []
def cek_paket(pkt):
    
    if pkt[ARP].op ==2:
        destinasi = str(pkt[ARP].pdst)
        source = str(pkt[ARP].psrc)
        dikirim = {'src':source,'dst':destinasi}
        if len(jumlah_reply)==0:
            dikirim['count']=1
            jumlah_reply.append(dikirim)
            found = True
        else:   
            found=False
            for itung in jumlah_reply:
                if itung['src']==dikirim['src'] and itung['dst']==dikirim['dst']:
                    itung['count']+=1
                    found = True
                    break
        if not found:
            jumlah_reply.append(dikirim)
            dikirim['count']=1
    print("reply")
    print(jumlah_reply)
    print("--------------------------------")

def delete_paket():
    if len(jumlah_reply) > 0:
        del jumlah_reply[0]
        print("*********************")
        print (jumlah_reply)
        print("**********************")
    time.sleep(3)
def sniffing():
    sniff(prn=cek_paket,filter="arp",store=0)

try:
    thread.start_new_thread(sniffing())
    thread.start_new_thread(delete_paket())
except:
    print("error")
while 1:
    pass
```

I was expecting the output:
When there is a ARP reply packet, the information will be added into the list, and 3 second after it, the first item will be deleted. but the actual output is
[image]

As you can see the information packet have added into the list but i've run the code for a minute there is no action from delete_reply() function. Why this is happen? is the sniff() function from scapy lock all the process?

Comment: There should be a loop in `delete_paket()`.

Comment: what kind of loop? i have tried that but it does not work.

Comment: Also you must not call the function when giving it as an argument to `start_new_thread()`